# What are the common inflection mistakes that Russian kids make?

Tags: грамматика

What are the common inflection mistakes that Russian kids make as they progress in mastering their first language?

Comment: A male friend of mine used to talk as a female (saying я пошла, поела, etc.) until he was about three and a half years old, because his mother talked to him in Russian, and his father in Armenian, so he didn't know any better :))

Comment: I feel this question is too open ended in its current form... I mean, any user could bring an example. Can we try to narrow it down?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan - HA HA! This is so hilarious!

Comment: This is not about Russian kids, but it's a funny error. A Russian language instructor in the US told me that she once had a student who, when speaking, could not clearly distinguish between он идёт and он идиот; when trying to say the first it came out sounding like the second.

Comment: @KCd HA HA HA!!!! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's typical of children (of Russian children, at least) to experiment with morphology. Korney Chukovsky wrote a book 'from 2 to 5' about his experience of childern from 2 to 5 understanding the undercurrent rules of Russian. It states such tendencies as

1. experimenting (- Дай другую логу! - логу instead of ложку. In fact, why not :) ? But we never say so, of course).
2. creating one's own etymology: Паутина (cobweb) -> паукина (as it has a spider, or паук there).
3. Widening the semantics: - Облака-то сняли! Сняли с неба облака! (we Russians don't 'take off' clouds from the sky).

I guess that's about it but the examples are fantastic! If you're interested in the book, you can find it on http://www.chukfamily.ru/Kornei/Prosa/Ot2do5/Ot2do5.htm. If you don't understand the Russian there, you can mail me to mari_belova@mail.ru. I've read the book and enjoyed it and I hope that you will enjoy it too!

In fact, as a linguist, I had lectures on children's language. So feel free to torture me with your curiosity :)))

Comment: Are there any examples of wrong usage of declensions or mixing up the cases (genitive, dative, instrumental, and so on)? It would be interesting to have examples of this.

Comment: I'm sorry I failed to find such examples... Maybe kids don't mix cases much, they just imitate what they hear?

Comment: I read somewhere that "лога" emerges because it is big from child's point of view, so it can't be "ложка". So does "скамейка", "кружка", "чашка" - "скамея", "кружа", "чаша", etc.

Answer (score 0):

My niece used to say "вчера" instead of "завтра".

Comment: Time concept was hard for my 3-years old daughter. For example "yesterday" was everything in the past (even several months ago).

Comment: @artemix, upvote the answer then